# can't execute a command even i'm in the group and command is -rwx--x---

Tags: shell-script, permissions, executable, group

I'm in `$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch` directory and when I type `opatch` then I get the response as,

```
-bash: opatch: command not found
```

If I do `./opatch`, then I get the response as,

```
/bin/sh: ./opatch: Permission denied
```

`ls -l` on `OPatch` shows `-rwx--x---`.

So for the group **oinstall**, it should have execute right and `id -g` confirms that the user belongs to the **oinstall** group.

So why I can't execute `opatch` in this case?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like `opatch` is a script. That is, it is a text file that starts with `#!` and lists its interpreter (maybe `/bin/sh`). Only compiled binaries (directly executable code) can be executed without read permission. For all scripts, no matter the interpreter (`sh`, `python`, etc...), the interpreter needs to be able to open the file, which mandates read permission plus execute permission.

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I do ls in the OPatch directory, there's a file named opatch without any file extension. Is it a compiled binaries by default?

Comment: @user1617237: Whether or not is is a compiled binary has nothing to do with its filename. It's more a metter of what programming language it's written in. I don't know what you mean by "by default". You can try to run `file` on it to see what it identifies. Under Linux or Solaris or others compiled binaries are in ELF format so that's what `file` will tell you. Otherwise `file` might tell you it's a script. `file` examines the contents in order to guess/determine this.

Comment: opatch:executable,regularfile,no read permission. if it's a executable, why it returns command not found when i just type in opatch?

Comment: It has something to do with my $PATH variable.

Comment: Thank you very much Celada. I figured it out. opatch is a executable script file which does need R and W to be able to run.

Comment: @user1617237 It needs R and X, not W.